# Conflict with hyperref's draft option, cleveref's \cref and... \textbf in \caption

Tags: hyperref, captions, cleveref, draft

The following MCE compiles like a charm.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\hypersetup{draft}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{%
    foo%
    % \textbf{foo}%
  }
  \label{bar}
\end{figure}

See \cref{bar}.
\end{document}
```

But, as soon as `% \textbf{foo}` is uncommented, the (second) compilation fails with:

```
! Use of \@@cref@getlabel doesn't match its definition.
\text@command #1->\edef \reserved@a {
                                     \unexpanded {#1}}\ifx \reserved@a \@emp...

l.36 See \cref{bar}
```

Then, if `\hypersetup{draft}` is commented, the compilation doesn't fail.

Do you understand what's going on?

### Edit: context

- Up to date TeX Live 2022
- Compilation with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`.
- My *File List*:

  ```
    article.cls    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
    size10.clo    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    varioref.sty    2021/07/07 v1.6f package for extended references (FMi)
    hyperref.sty    2022-05-17 v7.00q Hypertext links for LaTeX
    ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
    iftex.sty    2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
    pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
    infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
    keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
    kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
    kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
    pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
    hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
    letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
    auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
    nameref.sty    2022-05-17 v2.50 Cross-referencing by name of section
    refcount.sty    2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
    gettitlestring.sty    2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
    kvoptions.sty    2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
    pd1enc.def    2022-05-17 v7.00q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
    intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
    etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
    puenc.def    2022-05-17 v7.00q Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
    url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
    bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
    bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
    atbegshi-ltx.sty    2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
    hpdftex.def    2022-05-17 v7.00q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
    atveryend-ltx.sty    2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend packa
    rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
    uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
    cleveref.sty    2018/03/27 v0.21.4 Intelligent cross-referencing
    l3backend-pdftex.def    2022-04-20 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
     ***********
  ```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. It compiles fine for me if I uncomment `\textbf{foo}`, whether or not I have the `\hypersetup` line. What TeX distribution and version are you running, and what version of the packages? (This info is in the log file.)

Comment: @frabjous Context added. Dis you compile twice?

Comment: Yes, I compiled plenty of times, but I was actually using an older version of hyperref (2022-02-21 v7.00n); I do get your error if I upgrade to the 2022-05-17 7.00q version, so it must be something new in there.

Comment: Issue [reported](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/238) and a fix is on its way.